# Agent Configuration format is Invalid

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Struggling with getting IoT Edge installed on our devices.  Have tried both Linux and Windows 10 and always end up with the Edge Agent reporting "Agent Configuration format is Invalid" when we try and push the tempSensor container from the walk-through to the device.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please detail the steps how you created the tempSensor container?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by an issue on the Azure Portal yesterday.  The deployment schema was changed on the portal, which caused the current preview release some difficulty.  A change has been rolled out on the portal to revert the schema on the portal.

However, this does require you to submit the deployment again, so that the correct schema is generated.